# Datagrid Is Showing Rows With Nothing In Them using c# and sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, sql-server-2008, datagrid

so I've been working on this datagrid stuff and ran into another problem.  So, I have this textchanged event on a textbox that takes a barcode scanner input and matches that UML number to a table of movies(tblMovies).  It takes that row and inserts it into a cart table (tblCart).  When this happens I am trying to have  a datagrid in a wpf window, in visual studios using c#, populate the tblCart in it as it receives the new input.  So my problem I am having is that it will show an empty row with nothing in the cells.  Anybody have any idea why?

This is my datagrid in my XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dg1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="323" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="332" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Width="250" Binding="{Binding tblCart.Title}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="57" Binding="{Binding tblCart.Price}"/>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is my datagrid being initiated in the .cs:

```
public partial class SalesScreen : Window
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=******;Initial Catalog=*****;User ID=**; Password=**********");
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt;

    public SalesScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cn.Open();
        String cmdString = "Select Title, Price from tblCart";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, cn);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable("tblCart");
        da.Fill(dt);
        dg1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

And this is the textchanged method:

```
        private void TBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        String cmdString = "INSERT INTO tblCart(Title, GenreID, Price, Year, UML, Quantity) Select Title, GenreID, Price, Year, UML, Quantity FROM tblMovies WHERE UML = '" + BarcodeReader.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, cn);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable("tblCart");
        da.Fill(dt);
        dg1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

Once again I apologize if it is sloppy or being done wrong, but I am still learning. Any help to why my table is showing up with empty cells will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @marc_s nice sumary. About the question: Which fields are empty? Or are compleat empty lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already setting the itemsource to tblCart so when you type that in your xaml bindings its actually looking for tblCart.tblCart.Title (which obviously doesn't exist).

The following should do the trick (providing that your collection actually does contain data)

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Width="250" Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="57" Binding="{Binding Price}"/>
```

Comment: Great reply worked wonderfully.  Any idea how to make the datagrid update once the row is added?